# How to copy files from Mux to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil, mux-video

I use mux for video streaming and have been running direct uploads from the client browsers to Mux using [Upchunk](https://github.com/muxinc/upchunk) until recently when I decided to revamp the flow.

So now, I upload to a Google Storage bucket before using Mux PULL-BASED approach to create an asset with a reference to the file on GCS as input (an example is shown below). And it works really seamless.

```
// Create an asset
const asset = await Video.Assets.create({
  input: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/muxdemofiles/mux-video-intro.mp4',
});
```

Now I am trying to sync my files from Mux to my GCS bucket but don't want to use Google storage transfer service. I'm hoping that I can get a handle for my files on Mux storage bucket, GCS or S3, and use `GCP's gsutil` to copy the files to my storage bucket. Something like the this:

```
gsutil -h "Content-Type:video/mp4" -m cp gs://stream.mux.com/file-uuid/high.mp4 gs://mux-migration/video-files/-6mERHzSS-
```

Comment: Have you managed to try the command to see if you receive any error? In addition, could you please elaborate further on your use case, as there are many way to copy files within cloud storage providers. You may also check [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) which synchronizes the content of 2 directories.

Comment: Hi @ArtemisGeorgakopoulou, I ended up using a combination of Curl and gsutil. I first download the file using Curl then pipe it with gsutil to upload it to my GSC bucket.

`curl -L https://stream.mux.com/<playbackId>/<name> | gsutil -h "Content-Type:video/<ext>" cp - gs://<cloud-storage-bucket><folder>`

See the issue [here](https://github.com/muxinc/mux-node-sdk/issues/98) on github for an answer from a mux-node sdk maintainer